# Search string enclosed in quotes in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

In vim I need to search all strings in quotes e.g. 'foo'

Does one see the problem in this regex? **E486: Pattern not found \'([^']*)'**

```
:\/'([^']*)'
```

[Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/tbEnfS/1)

Comment: Hello (sorry for my manners)

Comment: Just use `/'([^']*)'`

Comment: FYI: there are >50 regex dialects, mostly incompatible to one another.  Vim uses one of these dialects, while regex tester sites use other dialects, incompatible to Vim.  I have yet to see such a site that knows about Vim regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that  your use of find is a bit  confusing. If you want
to  just find,  use `/`.  The colon  is not  necessary (which  indicates
command mode). If  you're using the find as a  range (basically the same
thing, `/` is just an empty command with a range) you can use the colon,
but either way escaping the first slash is not necessary.

The other main problem is that parenthesis by default need to be escaped
if  you meant  a  capturing group.  All  of this  is  dependant on  your
`'magic'` option reading  the help for the `/magic` topic  (you can do a
`:h  magic`) is  highly recommended.  With "vanilla"  Vim settings,  the
regex you need looks live this:

```
/'\([^']*\)'
```

With very magic  enable (by using the `\v` atom)  this can be simplified
to your original design:

```
/\v'([^']*)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use

`\v'(\a+)'`

this regex performs similar than yours, except when nested quotes are encountered. In the text:

```
The user's first 'answer'.
```

The regex `\v'(\a+)'` will capture `answer` while your original regex (corrected by sidyll) `\v'([^']*)'` will capture `'s first '`.